# What happens to Concentration spells while Blinking?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, concentration

I regularly see *blink* praised as a particularly good defensive third-level spell because, unlike many spells with persistent effects, it does not require concentration.  It does, however, state that "you can only affect and be affected by other creatures in the Material Plane."

I am uncertain about what exactly this means for concentration spells that are cast before the caster begins to *blink.*  So here are some specific questions:

- If I cast *hold person* and then *blink,* is the target still affected by *hold person* while I am on the Ethereal Plane?  (I believe the answer is no.)
- Targets can save from *hold person* at the end of their turn.  If the answer to the previous question is *no,* can the target save while they're not technically affected by the spell?  (I believe the answer is no, but this seems to be getting into weird territory, since they can only save when I fail to blink?)

Answer (score 6):

### A spell, once cast, is unaffected by the target or caster moving to another plane

Player's Handbook p.203

> Once a spell is cast, its effects aren’t limited by its range, unless the spell’s description says otherwise.

So long as you continue to concentrate, they will still be affected.

Comment: Hmm.  But the spell's description _does_ talk about the issue, and specifically says that you can't affect targets on the material plane.

Comment: Also by dropping concentration you would be affecting the creature on the Material Plane.